# Recorrer 2 posiciones por iteracion FOR

Tags: python, python-3.x, algoritmos

Buenas, nuestro primer for recorre 16 posiciones en este caso y queremos que tanto `padre`como `punto`tenga el mismo valor para cada 2 posiciones( Es decir, para `i=0` y `i=1` el mismo valor, para `i=2` y `i=3` otro....).

A continuación, si entra en el 2º FOR queremos que si la variable `i`es par haga lo que está dentro del IF y si no ELSE manteniendo para `i` y `i+1` los mismos valores de `padres`y `punto`

Cuando salga del segundo FOR, la `i` del primer for deberia avanzar dos posiciones y elegir nuevos valores para `padre`y `punto`

```
for i in range(len(poblacionNueva)-indAReproducir):
    padre = random.sample(selected, 2) #Se eligen dos padres
    punto = random.randint(1,largo-1) #Se elige un punto para hacer el intercambio
    while punto in listaVistos:
        punto = random.randint(1,largo-1)
    listaVistos.append(punto)

    if random.random() <= probabilidadReproduccion:
        print("i:%s"%(i))
        print("Padre:%s"%(padre))
        for i in range(i, i+1):
            if i%2==0:
                poblacionNuevaOrdenada[i][:punto] = (padre[0])[1][:punto] 
                print("Primera parteIF:%s"%(poblacionNuevaOrdenada[i][:punto]))

                poblacionNuevaOrdenada[i][punto:] = (padre[1])[1][punto:]
                print("Segunda parteIF:%s"%(poblacionNuevaOrdenada[i][punto:]))
            else:
                poblacionNuevaOrdenada[i][:punto] = (padre[1])[1][:punto] 
                print("Primera parteELSE:%s"%(poblacionNuevaOrdenada[i][:punto]))
                poblacionNuevaOrdenada[i][punto:] = (padre[0])[1][punto:]
                print("Segunda parteELSE:%s"%(poblacionNuevaOrdenada[i][punto:]))
            j = poblacionNuevaOrdenada[i][:punto] + poblacionNuevaOrdenada[i][punto:]

            print("Individuo Generado:%s"%(j))
            print("Poblacion Nueva FINAL:\n%s"%(poblacionNuevaOrdenada))
    else:
        poblacionNuevaOrdenada[i] = poblacionNuevaOrdenada[i]
        poblacionNuevaOrdenada[i+1] = poblacionNuevaOrdenada[i]
return poblacionNuevaOrdenada
```

**SOLUCION**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como veis, el valor de `padre` varia al igual que la variable `punto` de manera que las divisiones del numero la hace de manera incorrecta. Lo único correcto es la introduccion del individuo generado en la lista.

Answer (score 1):

Se me está dificultando ver exáctamente lo que desea lograr en su código porque está un poco complicado, un ejemplo más sencillo que muestra su dificultad sería más fácil contestar directamente. 
Sin embargo, la pregunta en el primer párrafo se puede contestar, y creo que le ayudará a usted a resolver su dificultad.

Los `for` pueden ir por dos, así que podrá lograr que sus listas tengan el mismo valor de `i=0` y `i=1` así con cada par de posiciones. Esto se hace usando el tercer parameter en `range()`

`range()` se usa como se ve al siguente

```
range(mínimo, máximo, paso)
```

donde paso es default 1, pero se puede especificar.

Ejemplo:

```
for i in range(0, 16, 2):
    print(i)
```

Resultado:

```
0
2
4
6
#... ecétera
14
```

Entonces, para hacer que cada dos posiciones tengan el mismo valor, se puede aprovechar este `for` así.

```
lista_final = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
for i in range(0, 16, 2):
    lista_final[i] = i
    lista_final[i+1] = i
print(lista_final)
```

Resultado:

```
[0, 0, 2, 2, 4, 4, 6, 6, 8, 8, 10, 10, 12, 12, 14, 14]
```

Espero que le sirve esta herramienta.